# Ionic 2 inspect observable before returning it

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic and Angular, and coming from years of .NET development. I'm trying a few examples online to build login prototype with Ionic 2.

I got WebAPI working in the background simply returning JSON true or false depending if credentials passed is correct or not.

I got authentication provider looking like this:

```
  public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {

        this.result = this.http.post(this.CONST.APIUrl, JSON.stringify(credentials), new RequestOptions({headers: this.contentHeader})).map(res => res.json())

        if (this.result)
        {
            this.currentUser = new User('Simon', 'saimon@devdactic.com');  
        }

        return this.result;

  }}
```

and login page looking like this:

```
public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage)
        });
      } else {
        this.showError("Access Denied");
      }
    },
    error => {
      this.showError(error);
    });
  }
```

At the moment it always logs person in. I understand that this is happening because this.result always has a value. But how would I check data returned from the API before allowing person to login?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Observable.do](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md) to create *side effects* for an Observable.

In login function:

```
public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {

        this.result = this.http.post(this.CONST.APIUrl,
          JSON.stringify(credentials), new RequestOptions({headers: this.contentHeader}))
           .map(res => res.json())
           .do(userData=>{
               //check userData and set current user
               this.currentUser = new User('Simon', 'saimon@devdactic.com');
               return userData;//make sure to return the value to subscribe  
           });
   return result;
  }}
```